# how to implement text with reference in Android

Tags: android, text, reference

I want to create a book in android. It's text come from database and every section of this text has a reference.I need to put clickable image inside text to show reference and when I click on image something like Toast which contain reference list will appear.
I didn't see something like that in typical app. any body have any suggestion to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you will have a clickable image inside the activity.  Next add a onClickListener to the image, inside of this display the toast with the reference.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "https://www.google.com/", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
}
```

If you have multiple clickable images then you might be better off implementing the interface View.OnClickListener and adding the onClick method.

Comment: in fact i have dynamic text with multiple image inside text . i do not have xml code for image .images should create programitically

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use `Linkify` class provided by Android Framework - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html for details.

Also you can play with google sample - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-TextLinkify

Comment: thank you ,but i do not need to open browser or call anyone when i click on image.i need to see a text after click on image